# Silverstripe install.php can't find <mysite>

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have working SS v3.4 project locally. Now I want to deploy it. I've copied files to the server, run `composer install` to install vendor libraries. When I run `install.php` all requirements are fine except for missing `mysite` folder errors. That's intended because I renamed my project folder to let's say `mydomain` and it works fine on localhost. AFAIK SS should pick up the custom folder and recognise it as THE page folder. Somehow it doesn't happen. Any ideas why?

Comment: Have you tried running the database build at `/dev/build`?

Comment: Yes, it did populate the DB but didn't help with this step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected, since the installer specifically looks for "mysite".

You probably have two options:

- Rename `app` to `mysite` on the serve, re-run the installer then rename the folder back to `app`
- Don't run the installer at all - if you configure your own `_ss_environment.php` file and ensure `assets` folder is writeable you shouldn't need it

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I did something else in the meantime: I copied the local db to the server and it sort of works now, i.e. the site works fine with all the pages but I can't log into the admin (there's 500 returned in admin pages) for some reason.