# SilverStripe dev mode and admin panel break the page

Tags: php, mysqli, silverstripe

I have localhost SS 3.4 project, which works fine. Same project on the server works fine with one exception. I can't access the CMS (nor set the page to dev mode) I get server error, which logs as problem with DB connection:

Warning at framework/model/connect/MySQLiConnector.phpline 77: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host ''

and:

Error at framework/model/connect/DBConnector.php line 55: Uncaught SS_DatabaseException: Couldn't connect to MySQL database | Unknown MySQL server host ''

Which is strange because the page uses the DB connection all the time to render content... Any idea how to figure this out?

Comment: How did you configure DB on the server? Maybe it's missing a proper `_ss_environment.php` or you just misconfigured db config.

Comment: I used to use _config.php but I switched to _ss_environment.php -
it didn't help. Anyway, the page works (the content is displayed) so it's able to connect to the DB, at least for reading purposes. I just had to clone whole local DB to the server to achieve that, cause I couldn't log into the admin. Is there any server specific info in the DB that can prevent the CMS from working? I couldn't find any.

Comment: Here's the original installation problem I encountered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48810203/silverstripe-install-php-cant-find-mysite/48819128#48819128 and the solution.

Comment: You have a working installation on localhost? The server is pretty the same configuration? Same DB, same PHP-Version etc...? Your code is in a version control (like git) to update it easily on the server? You installed SilverStripe locally using composer? Theoretically you "just" have to make sure, the code on the server is the same, your db credentials are set (use _ss_environment.php for it on a SS3 site, ENV on SS4), copy over assets and put your local DB dump in the live DB.

Comment: For copying assets and DB there is a tool called "sspak" that might help you. But to get this working you need db configured properly.

Comment: Yes the localhost works all fine. I push the code with rsync, I installed vendors using composer via ssh on the server. There is a slight PHP  version difference PHP Version 5.4.17 online vs PHP Version 5.5.36 locally  but it's still within SS 3.4 requirements and the install script doesn't complain about it. I managed to narrow down the problem so far to mysqli connection during admin login. For some reason it complains about either unknown host or (if supplied) wrong type of port argument (string vs long) which I temporarily hardcoded as 3306 into the mysqli constructor call.

Comment: I even managed to set it up correctly on another server at the same provider. The only difference I'm aware of is the PHP version (5.6 on this one) so maybe that's the way to go. Too bad the PHP upgrade on the proper server I have to work with is probably another kind of nightmare due to some legacy apps sharing the same PHP. Anyway thanks for  confirming this theoretically SHOULD work.

Comment: It might be that your local composer installed some packages that didn't work on PHP5.4 on the server. I really love my hosting where I can switch php versions per account / customer project.

Comment: That's client's hosting unfortunately... Anyway I installed deps using remote composer (via the target server shell), but it does look like some modules mismatch.

Comment: You can add the maximum PHP Version to your composer.json, then your local composer won't require anything that doesn't work with PHP5.4. If you have locally 5.6 it'll require newer versions which are written to your composer.lock file. If you run `composer install` on the server, it "just" installs what you require in the .lock file - without checking any dependencies.

Comment: That's a very good point. I somehow took it for granted that the server side installation will take PHP version into account.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, as wmk suggested it was most probably question of using local composer's lock file to install dependencies on the server despite different local and remote PHP versions (5.4 vs 5.5). After adding `platform` option to `composer.json` and reinstalling deps the problem disappeared.

```
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "5.4.17"
    }
},
```